# When to enclose statements within braces in a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

In a program to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* print Fahrenheit-Celsius table
for fahr = 0, 20, ..., 300 */
main()
{
  int fahr, celsius;
  int lower, upper, step;
  lower = 0; /* lower limit of temperature scale */
  upper = 300; /* upper limit */
  step = 20; /* step size */
  fahr = lower;
  while (fahr <= upper) {
    celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
    printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
    fahr = fahr + step;
  }
}
```

we enclose the three statements in the while loop within braces.....BUT
in the program to count characters-

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input*/
main()
{
  long nc;
  nc = 0;
  while (getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;
  printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

we dont enclose the two statements in the while loop within Braces...
Why so?

Comment: isn't executing the statements multiple times the main function of while loop?

Comment: This is why formatting your code is important!

Comment: You need to read a beginner-level C programming book for the utterly basic stuff. SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial to replace studies.

Comment: There are no "two statements in the `while` loop" if there are no braces.

Answer (score 1):

C allows for a single statment to be written without brackets:

```
for (;;)
    statment;

if ()
    statment;
else
    statment;
// do, while etc...
```

However, this is bad practice - since as you can see - this can cause confusion

```
for (;;)
    count++;
    printf("%d", count);
```

especially when code is indented, it will seem that the `printf` statment would be executed on each loop iteration, It won't. you should always use brackets to avoid this confusion.

from experiance - when neglecting to do so, the code you produce might seem cleaner but in the long run might be very hard to debug errors and might cause overlooking simple bugs

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say it is "bad practice", but you could say always enclosing the loop commands in braces makes the code "more readable" (especially for new C programmers)

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet is equivalent to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input*/
main()
{
  long nc;
  nc = 0;
  while (getchar() != EOF)
  {
    ++nc;
  }
  printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

and not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input*/
main()
{
  long nc;
  nc = 0;
  while (getchar() != EOF)
  {
    ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
  }
}
```

As you can see, only the first line (`++nc`) is considered. To avoid confusion, I always include brackets on if statements and loops.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a while-loop (formally a kind of *iteration-statement*) is

> while ( expression ) statement

Note that *statement* is singular - only one statement allowed:

```
while (getchar() != EOF)
  ++nc;
```

But by enclosing several statements in `{` and `}` you create a *compound-statement* that can package several statements, but grammatically still be treated as a *statement*.

```
while (getchar() != EOF)
{
   ++nc;
   printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

So you use the brackets `{` and `}` to bundle code and declarations that should be treated as a unit. You don't have to do that (but are still allowed to) when the code is only a single statement anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the counting of characters you want to execute the loop only for 1 statement.

But in the temperature conversion program we have to execute 3 statements inside the loop therefore we require the curly braces.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i,sum=0;
  for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {  
    sum+=i;              //Loop will be only executed on this statement
    printf("Hello\n");  //Loop will also be executed on this statement
  } 
}
```

If in any loop we do not use the curly braces it means that the loop is required on the immediate next statement only.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i,sum=0;
  for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    sum+=i;            //Loop will be only executed on this statement
  printf("Hello\n");
}
```

I hope now the difference is clear.
The same is the case for any statement with curly braces like "if","else",etc.

Answer (score 0):

**While-Loop   Syntax   :**

```
while (expression) {
     //statement 1
     //statement 2
}
```

If we have only **single statement** to execute within our Loop (i.e in our case while-loop) then we can either write :

**Form 1:**

```
while (expression) {
         //statement 1 
    }
```

*Or we can write it as :*

**Form 2:**

```
while (expression) 
         //statement 1
```

> NOTE: If we write one more statement below statement 1 (in Form 2)
>   then it will not be executed within loop body.